# Alert message only if a value is present in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am looking to get an alert box only if a value in the cell is present, but whenever I remove the cell value, the alert message prompts. Here is the code

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var trix = sheet.getSheetByName('Response');
var status = trix.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 5).getValues();
var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = sh.alert("Do you want to send an email?", sh.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
if (response == sh.Button.YES){
 if (e.range.columnStart == 5 || e.value == "Approved" || e.value == "Rejected" || e.value == "Duplicate"){
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 5).getValues();
    
    let EmployeeName = rData[0][2];
    let Reviewer = rData[0][4];
    let Status = rData[0][5];
    Logger.log(Status);
var UpdateEmail =
      ('<html>' +
           '<body>' +
            '<head>' +
            '<style>table, th,tr{border: 2px solid black;}</style>' +
            '</head>' +
            '<tr style="background-color:#d3ecdc;"><td width=500 height=auto; colspan=6><br>Hi ' + EmployeeName + ',<br><br> Your suggestion has been ' + Status + ' by ' + Reviewer + '<br> you can check the comments here <br><br>Regards,<br>"Rajanee"<br><br></td></tr>' +
           '</body>' +
           '</html>')
    // Logger.log(UpdateEmail);
    // GmailApp.sendEmail("EmployeeName", "Approved Order", msg)

    MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: EmployeeName,
      subject: 'Idea Status!',
    htmlBody: UpdateEmail,
        name: 'Ideas',
        cc: ccmail
    });
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

#### To:

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.isBlank()) return; // Added
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

- By this modification, when the cell is empty, the script below `if (e.range.isBlank()) return;` is not run.

### Added:

About your following reply,

> I'd want emails not to trigger when a condition is met, but there aren't any values in a specific row. Current scenario: I enter a value in Cell 5, an alert prompts (yes/no), when I choose yes, an email will be sent. When there are no values in a specific row, I want to restrict email being sent even if I chose yes on the alert prompt

If your actual expected result is in your reply in the comment, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Response";
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != 5 || range.isBlank()) return;
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const response = sh.alert("Do you want to send an email?", sh.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response != sh.Button.YES || !["Approved", "Rejected", "Duplicate"].includes(range.getValue())) return;

  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 5).getValues();
  let EmployeeName = rData[0][2];
  let Reviewer = rData[0][4];
  let Status = rData[0][5];
  Logger.log(Status);
  var UpdateEmail =
    ('<html>' +
      '<body>' +
      '<head>' +
      '<style>table, th,tr{border: 2px solid black;}</style>' +
      '</head>' +
      '<tr style="background-color:#d3ecdc;"><td width=500 height=auto; colspan=6><br>Hi ' + EmployeeName + ',<br><br> Your suggestion has been ' + Status + ' by ' + Reviewer + '<br> you can check the comments here <br><br>Regards,<br>"Rajanee"<br><br></td></tr>' +
      '</body>' +
      '</html>')
  MailApp.sendEmail({ to: EmployeeName, subject: 'Idea Status!', htmlBody: UpdateEmail, name: 'Ideas', cc: ccmail });
}
```

- In this modification, when a value is put to column "E" of "Response" sheet, a dialog is opened. When "OK" button is clicked, the value is checked, and when the value is `"Approved", "Rejected", "Duplicate"`, an email is sent. When the value is not `"Approved", "Rejected", "Duplicate"`, the email is not sent.

Comment: The alert pops up even when the edit is made in other cells. I'd want to restrict it to only when an edit is made in column 5.

Comment: @Rocking Raghav Thank you for replying. From `but whenever I remove the cell value, the alert message prompts.`, I thought that you wanted to check the empty cell. I apologize for my poor English skill. From `The alert pops up even when the edit is made in other cells. I'd want to restrict it to only when an edit is made in column 5.`, in this case, how about `if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.range.isBlank()) return;` instead of `if (e.range.isBlank()) return;`?

Comment: @Rocking Raghav Or, if you want to also check the inputted value, how about `if (e.range.columnStart != 5 || e.range.isBlank() || !["Approved", "Rejected", "Duplicate"].includes(e.range.getValue())) return;` instead of `if (e.range.isBlank()) return;`? If I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize.

Comment: Apologies for the mistake.   0


Apologies for the mistakes. I'd want emails not to trigger when a condition is met, but there aren't any values in a specific row.
Current scenario:
I enter a value in Cell 5, an alert prompts (yes/no), when I choose yes, an email will be sent. When there are no values in a specific row, I want to restrict email being sent even if I chose yes on the alert prompt

Comment: @Rocking Raghav Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I understood that your question was different from your actual expected result. By this, my initial answer is not useful for your actual expected result. I deeply apologize for this. So, I added one more modified script for your actual expected result, please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected result, I apologize again.

Comment: @Rocking Raghav By the way, about your new question, reflected my proposed answer, I think that it is a duplicate question of your this question. So, I flagged it as a duplicated question.